# IE and Safari jQuery Syntax Error

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, safari

Can anyone explain why this syntax does not work in Safari or Internet Explorer:

```
$('#something').attr({src: src_url, class:class_name});
```

IE, "Expected indentifier, string or number". And why do they require src and class to be strings like:

```
$('#something').attr({'src': src_url, 'class': class_name});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

> WARNING: When setting the 'class' attribute, you must always use quotes!

Answer (score 0):

The `src` property should work without apostrophes, but `class` is a reserved keyword so it can't be used as an identifier, it has to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

this is directly from the jQuery API docs:

> When setting multiple attributes, the quotes around attribute names are optional.
>
> WARNING: When setting the 'class' attribute, you must always use quotes!
>
> Note: Internet Explorer does not allow you to change the type attribute of an  or  element.